# mysql only runs as root

Tags: mysql, macports

I've just recently installed my Macports MAMP environment and I thought I'd followed the directions, but couldn't get MySQL to run. After much wrangling and testing, I've stumbled upon what the problem is, but I have no idea how to solve it.

I was getting the classic, irritating "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" error message. Checking and rechecking, the socket file was exactly where MySQL expected it to be and was set to the right permissions. Then, while trying to troubleshoot, I attempted to log in while I was still in superuser and boom! I was in!!

Leave superuser and it no longer works. Doh!

So my question is: how might I correct this problem and get it to run as a regular user? The trouble with Google searching a topic like this is that the two user systems - MySQL and Mac - are getting confused and I'm not finding the solution I need.

Thanks very much!

A brief example of the problem:

`tomb# mysql -u root -p thisismypassword

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql55/mysqld.sock' (13)

tomb#sudo su

Password:

sh-3.2#mysql -u root -p thisismypassword

mysql >`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know have an answer, but I noticed several "Related" posts (in the right margin on this page) that look like they might be related... hopefully/maybe have some other hints for you to try

Comment: I should also include this small example of exactly the problem:

`tomb# mysql -u root -p thisismypassword

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql55/mysqld.sock' (13)


tomb#sudo su
Password:

sh-3.2#mysql -u root -p thisismypassword
mysql >`